# How to disable direct entry to a html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, url

Say I have two html files called html1 and html2. html1 contains an embedded swf file.

Now what I want is that the user can not go to html2 directly via url. He has to click it through the link in the swf in html1. Is there a way to achieve this?

If not possible in html, is it possible with php?

Thanks

EDIT:

After answer from John, I went ahead and tried his advice, but I can never access the file2.php, even if I have been to file1.php before. It keeps redirecting me back to file1.php, even when it should not.

My code from file1.php

```
//file1.php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['enableAccessTill']=strtotime("+5 minutes");
?>
```

Here is file2.php

```
//file2.php
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['enableAccessTil'])||$_SESSION['enableAccessTil']<time())
{
header("Location: indexFLA.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

what am I possibly doing wrong?

found it, it was due to a misspelling - "enableAccessTil" and "enableAccessTill"

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Flash so I don't know if this is possible, but if Flash can push a cookie, you could have it push a cookie that expires in 30 seconds, and the 2nd HTML file (which would need PHP) would check for the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wont be possible in just plain html.
An easy way to do this is php is by setting a session variable in file 1, and test in file 2 it the users has been to file 1.

file1:

```
 <?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['enableAccessTill'] = strtotime("+5 minutes"); //set the time here till when the user has access
   [...]
```

file2

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset( $_SESSION['enableAccessTill'] ) || $_SESSION['enableAccessTill'] < time() ){ //If time is expired
    header("Location: file1.php"); //redirect user to the first file
    exit;
  }
[...] //continue your script here.
```

Things with referrer check do usually fail (some browsers/firewalls blocking that variable).

Comment: what if the user visits file1 and then leaves it. Will he then be able to get access to file2 directly?

Comment: If he doesnt close his browser, he will be able to do that.

Comment: no true!! you can use only html.. pls edit you comment... http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: @John Is there a work-around for that, like if the user leaves the page, the session resets or something like that?

Comment: I call shenanigans on the "usually". Chrome certainly doesn't seem to have a setting to block that header, and neither should nonbroken firewalls / proxies. (The header is a privacy concern more than a security one.)

Comment: @AnkurSharma You can't really tell when the user leaves the page. You can however just have the permission time out. Just store a date instead of a boolean in the session.

Comment: No, not a foolproof solution. You could use a timer though. I edit my awnser to put in a timer. You can set the timer to like a few minutes, so it will expire after that time.

Comment: Thanks John, I went ahead and tried your code but it does not work as expected, look at the edit in the question.

Comment: found the problem, it was due to a misspelling, thanks very much. it works as expected now. but one thing that I was wondering about is whether I can pass things like username and password through the $_SESSION variables or not. Is it safe?

Comment: yes, $_SESSION is considered save (server side). But make sure to hash a password first ( `hash("sha512", $password);`

Answer (score 3):

professional solution:
create protected directory and make `.htaccess` file in directory and copy all embedded and partial files into directory.
this directory not accessible whit get url.
but you can include file whit php `include` and `require` method.
.htaccess content:

```
deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the options you described, it would sound most reasonable to make the html2 a `php` script and check that the [referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) is the html1 file. The script should display the normal html1 content if that is the case, or an error message otherwise.

A sneaky user could still get around this if they knew what was going on, but it should be fine for the majority of your audience.

Comment: Some browsers don't respond to the PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` request, and on others it's very easy to spoof.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with php.

At index.php you must write

```
<?php
define('START', true);
include 'file.php';
```

At file.php need write

```
<?php defined('START) or die('Direct access!!'); ?>
<embed> your swf file embed
```

This way you will prevent direct access

Comment: This won't even remotely do what the OP wanted. The check has to be done across two requests.

Comment: what if somebody visit index.php once, and then leaves it. Will he be able to get direct access to file.php?

Comment: @AnkurSharma Good application must have one entry point - index.php

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with PHP by using session variables. Start the session in html1. Check for the session in html2. If it exists, display html2. If it does not, don't display html2. In either case, destroy the session in html2.

Answer (score 0):

well is posible with html you has two options one is cookies and the other is local storage in html5

```
localStorage.hasClick = true;

alert(localStorage.hasClick);
```

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

but obviously the straightforward solution is php / c# / ruby / etc...

//when I said html i refer to use only client side html/javascript